# Make one Checkbox depend on another in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have two check boxes (ON/OFF) that I want to make dependent in jQuery, this means that when I check the first (checkbox1) ON, the second (checkbox2) will automatically turn ON, i've tried this solution but it not works, can someone help me please.

```
//php
 $cus_centre = $this->createElement('checkbox', 'checkbox1');
        $cus_centre->setLabel($translate->_("Checkbox1"));
        // ->setAttrib("disabled", "disabled");
        $this->addElement($cus_centre);

    $checkbox2 = $this->createElement('checkbox', 'checkbox2');
    $checkbox2->setLabel($translate->_("Checkbox2"));
    // ->setAttrib("disabled", "disabled");
    $this->addElement($checkbox2);   

//jQuery
      $('#checkbox1').iphoneStyle({
            onChange:function(){
            if($("#checkbox1").is(':checked')){
                $("#checkbox1").val(1);
                $("#checkbox2").attr('checked', true);
                $("#checkbox2").val(1);

          }
       }
   });
```

[My Checkboxes view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8uhT.png)

Comment: Are not two or more dependent checkboxes called "Radio"? A checkbox is supposed to be independent. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Comment: radios only allow one on at a time - the OP wants to tie them together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it simply like this. Using `$(this)` inside the function (change listener) to check if the first checkbox is checked. If so, it will mark the second one.

```
$('#checkbox1').change(function() {
  if(this.checked) {
    $("#checkbox2").prop("checked", true);
  } 
});
```

Comment: I tested that but it does not work, I manage to enter the loop correctly but the code $("#checkbox2").prop('checked', true); change nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```js
$('#chkBox1').change(() => {
  $('#chkBox2').prop('checked', $('#chkBox1').prop('checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="chkBox1" type="checkbox">
<input id="chkBox2" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: I tested that but it does not work, I manage to enter the loop correctly but the code  $("#checkbox2").prop('checked', true); change nothing

Comment: Did you run my code snippet? It works fine on mine.

Comment: yes i've runned the code and that's not work, i've replaced 'checked' by 'disabled' and it works, it means that the problem is on the 'checked' parameter

Comment: what browser are you using? And version please